# traceroute doesnt recognize incoming router responds

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, networking, winsock

I made my own realization of **traceroute** utility. Responds from routers are not catched by the program (`select()` returns zero for reading **ICMP** socket in `fd_set` given as the argument), but sniffer intercepts it:[image: scrrenshot of Wireshark]

Also **ICMP** packets are sended with the network address as a destination, but 
i specified `h_addr` of `HOSTENT` struct in `SOCKADDR` struct.

The `main()` code:

```
#include "winsock_error.h"
#include "io_ext.h"
#include <cstdio>

#define SOCK_NUM 3

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

WSADATA filler;

if (WSAStartup(WSA_VERSION, &filler)) {
    output_error("Couldn't initialize WSA");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

char host_name[MAXGETHOSTSTRUCT];

enter_message("Please enter a host name: ", host_name);
std::cout << std::endl;

LPHOSTENT remote_host_info = gethostbyname(host_name);

if (remote_host_info == NULL) {
    output_error("Couldn't get a host info");
    finalize();

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (remote_host_info->h_addrtype == AF_INET6) {
    output_error("Sorry, but R-Scan can't perform scanning of ipv6-hosts");
    finalize();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//ALIASES SHOWING
if (remote_host_info->h_aliases[0]) {
    std::cout << "Server name aliases: " << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; remote_host_info->h_aliases[i]; i++)
        std::cout << remote_host_info->h_aliases[i] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
else
    std::cout << "Host has no aliases" << std::endl
              << std::endl;

in_addr tmp;

//ADDRESSES SHOWING
if (remote_host_info->h_addr_list[1]) {
    std::cout << "Server addresses: " << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; remote_host_info->h_addr_list[i]; i++) {
        tmp.s_addr = *(LPDWORD)remote_host_info->h_addr_list[i];
        std::cout << inet_ntoa(tmp) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Server address: ";
    tmp.s_addr = *(u_long*)remote_host_info->h_addr;
    std::cout << inet_ntoa(tmp) << std::endl
              << std::endl;
}

WORD temp;
BYTE max_hops_num;

//MAX HOPS NUM INPUT
while (true) {
    std::cout << "Please enter max number of hops: ";
    (std::cin >> temp).get();

    if (!std::cin || temp > TTL_MAX_VAL || temp == 0) {
        clear_istream(std::cin);
        std::cerr << "You entered wrong value; try again" << std::endl
                  << std::endl;
    }
    else
        break;
}

__asm //firstly value is assigned to 16 bit temporary variable, then left octet of temporary variable is assigned to max_hops_num variable
{
push ax
mov ax, temp
mov max_hops_num, al
pop ax
}

fd_set read;
SOCKET sock = ICMP_SOCKET;
sockaddr_in server_data;
ECHO_REQUEST echo_req;
ECHO_REPLY echo_rep;
timeval wait_time = { 2, 0 };

//CONNECTION DATA FILLING
server_data.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_data.sin_port = 0;
tmp.s_addr = *(LPDWORD)remote_host_info->h_addr;
inet_pton(AF_INET, (PCSTR)inet_ntoa(tmp), &server_data.sin_addr);

//ICMP HDR AND ECHO_REQUEST STRUCT FILLING
echo_req.icmp_hdr.type = ICMP_ECHO_REQ;
echo_req.icmp_hdr.code = 0;
echo_req.icmp_hdr.id = 1;
echo_req.icmp_hdr.seq = 0;
echo_req.icmp_hdr.checksum = 0;
echo_req.dw_time = GetTickCount();
memset(echo_req.data, ECHO_FILLER, PACK_FRAME_SIZE);
echo_req.icmp_hdr.checksum = checksum((LPWORD)&echo_req, sizeof(echo_req));

//TRACERT LOOP
for (BYTE TTL = 1; TTL <= max_hops_num; TTL++) {
    tmp.s_addr = 0;
    printf("%3d\t", TTL);

    //set TTL
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, (PCSTR)&TTL, sizeof(TTL)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error_to_close_socket("Couldn't set IP header TTL", sock);
        finalize();

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //send 3 ICMP echo requests
    RANGE(0, SOCK_NUM)
    {
        echo_req.dw_time = GetTickCount();
        echo_req.icmp_hdr.checksum = checksum((LPWORD)&echo_req, sizeof(echo_req));

        if (sendto(sock, (PCSTR)&echo_req, sizeof(echo_req), 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&server_data, sizeof(server_data)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            error_to_close_socket("Couldn't perform a ping", sock);
            finalize();

            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        FD_ZERO(&read);
        FD_SET(sock, &read);

        int ret = select(0, &read, NULL, NULL, &wait_time);

        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            error_to_close_socket("Couldn't perform data awaiting", sock);
            finalize();

            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else if (ret == 0) {
            std::cout << " * \t";
        }
        else {
            if (recvfrom(sock, (LPSTR)&echo_rep, sizeof(ECHO_REPLY), 0, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                error_to_close_socket("Couldn't receive ICMP", sock);
                finalize();

                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            printf("%4d ms\t", GetTickCount() - echo_rep.echo_request.dw_time);
            tmp = echo_rep.ip_hdr.src_addr;
        }
    }

    if (tmp.s_addr == 0) {
        std::cout << "Waiting time exceeded" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    remote_host_info = gethostbyaddr((PCSTR)&echo_rep.ip_hdr.src_addr, AF_INET_ADDR_LEN, AF_INET);

    if (remote_host_info == NULL)
        std::cout << inet_ntoa(echo_rep.ip_hdr.src_addr) << std::endl;
    else
        printf("%s [%s]", remote_host_info->h_name, inet_ntoa(echo_rep.ip_hdr.src_addr));

    if (echo_rep.echo_request.icmp_hdr.type == 0 && echo_rep.echo_request.icmp_hdr.code == 0)
        break;
}

finalize();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Header file:

```
    #pragma once
#ifndef WINSOCK_ERROR
#define WINSOCK_ERROR

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#define ECHO_PORT 32768
#define WSA_VERSION 0x0202
#define LOCALHOST "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFF_SIZE 8192
#define BACKLOG 4
#define WAIT_TIME 1
#define INPUT_BUFF 16
#define PACK_FRAME_SIZE 64
#define REPLY_DATA_SIZE 0x100
#define TTL_MAX_VAL 0xFF
#define ICMP_ECHO_REQ 8
#define ECHO_FILLER 87
#define EVERLAST_HOPS_PARAM 0
#define AF_INET_ADDR_LEN 4
#define TCP_SOCKET socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)
#define UDP_SOCKET socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP)
#define ICMP_SOCKET socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_ICMP)

namespace con_mode 
{

enum mode 
  { 
write,          //socket condition for sending data
    read,           //socket condition for receiving data
    input,          //socket condition for entering data by user
    timeout         //socket condition for inactivity
  };

} 

typedef struct ICMP_hdr //ICMP header representation

{

BYTE type;

BYTE code;

WORD checksum;

WORD id;

WORD seq;

} ICMP_HDR;


typedef struct echo_request //packet that will be sent through the network
{

ICMP_HDR icmp_hdr;

DWORD dw_time;

char data[PACK_FRAME_SIZE];

} ECHO_REQUEST;


typedef struct ip_hdr 
{

BYTE ver_ihl;       //4 bit for version, 4 bit for internet header length (in DWORDs)
  BYTE dscp_ecn;        //DiffServ: 6 bit for dscp (packet priority or ToS) and 2 bit ECN (congestion flag); if congestion exists, transmission rate reduces 
  WORD tot_len;         //length of header + data, 16 bit field
  WORD id;          //for packet fragments identifying (if a packet was fragmented)
  WORD flag_off;        //flags of fragmentation and fragment offset; 1st bit - reserved; 2nd bit - if set, packet won't be fragmented if it need and will be dropped;
  //3rd bit - set for all fragmented packets; fragment offset - 13 bit field, defines a fragment offset relative to the beginnig of original IP datagram; measured in 64 bit blocks
  BYTE TTL;         //time-to-live, 8 bit field; measured determined bu the number of gateways and hosts packet can traverse
  BYTE protocol;        //8 bit field; protocol list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers
  WORD checksum;        //16 bit field; if it hasn't been computed yet, it must be equal to 0
  in_addr src_addr;     //32 bit sender IP address
  in_addr dst_addr;     //32 bit receiver IP address
} IP_HDR;


typedef struct echo_reply   //ICMP echo response from server
{

IP_HDR ip_hdr;

ECHO_REQUEST echo_request;

char c_filler[REPLY_DATA_SIZE];

} ECHO_REPLY;


inline USHORT checksum (USHORT * buffer, int size) 
{

unsigned long cksum = 0;


while (size > 1)

    {

cksum += *buffer++;

size -= sizeof (USHORT);

}

if (size)

    {

cksum += *(UCHAR *) buffer;

}

cksum = (cksum >> 16) + (cksum & 0xffff);

cksum += (cksum >> 16);

return (USHORT) (~cksum);

}



inline void
output_error (const char *message) 
{

SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

std::cerr << message << std::endl;

std::cerr << "Error code: " << WSAGetLastError () << std::endl;

SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

} 

inline void

finalize () 
{

WSACleanup ();

system ("pause");

} 

inline void

close_socket (SOCKET sock) 
{

if (closesocket (sock) == SOCKET_ERROR)

    {

SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

std::
    cerr << "Couldn't close socket: error " << WSAGetLastError () << std::
    endl;

SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

}

}



inline void
error_to_close_socket (const char *message, SOCKET sock) 
{

SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);


output_error (message);

close_socket (sock);


SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                  FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

} 

#endif
```

Screenshot of performing:

[image: waiting time exceeded everywhere]

OS Windows 10 ver. 10.0.15063

Comment: Just wondering why you need the assembly code `__asm {
mov ax, temp
mov max_hops_num, al
}`. This looks highly fishy to me.

Comment: This code assigns lower 8 bits of `temp` variable to `max_hops_num` variable. This method is more convenient for me.

Comment: In your screenshot, you do not have a valid server address. That is a network address, not a host address.

Comment: The same code in my **ping** utility outputss normal addresses. I don't know why it doesn't work here. Looks like it's problem with `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: Where is the code that actually creates the `ICMP_SOCKET` socket that you are sending and receiving with?

Comment: `SOCKET sock = ICMP_SOCKET;`, where `ICMP_SOCKET` is a macro in the header:`#define ICMP_SOCKET socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_ICMP)`

Comment: @zergon321 what's wrong with `max_hops_num = temp & 0xff` instead of your asm code? Just curious. The code generated by the compiler might be even smarter.